how to center Spinner in kivy
I started learning kivy and stopped at the stage with .kv files. The block with Spining is stuck to the corner and I can't put it in the center
//python file
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('widgets.kv')
        return countryLists()

class countryLists(Widget):
    def countryList(self):
        return pd.read_csv('./data.csv')['Country'].tolist()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()

// .kv file
:
Spinner:
    id: spinner1
    text: 'select country'
    values: root.countryList()

    font_size: 24
    bold: True
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
    anchor: 'center'

I tryed use anchor: 'center', tryed use BoxLayout, change  pos_hint, nothing to work
enter image description here
